# Null coalescing within an invocation chain

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception, null-coalescing-operator

If I have a long list of objects that each has the possibility of returning null within a "Linq where" clause, e.g.

```
 SomeSource.Where(srcItem=>(srcItem.DataMembers["SomeText"].Connection.ConnectedTo as Type1).Handler.ForceInvocation == true));
```

the indexer can return null and the "as" operator may return null. It is possible that the object does not have a connection (ie. The property is null). 
If a null is encountered anywhere, I would like the where clause to return "false" for the item being evaluated. Instead, it aborts with a null reference exception.

It appears to me that this would be contrived to express within a single C# expression. I don't like to create a multi line statement or create a separate func for it.
Is there some use of the null coalescing operator that I'm missing?

Comment: This would be a really nice feature

Comment: One option is to create a VS helper action which would simply expand `a.b.c` to, say, `a == null ? null : (a.b == null ? null : a.b.c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `.?` operator (or is it `?.`—one of those, anyway), which does not exist in C# (though it is an often-requested feature, according to Eric Lippert).

The only *possible* suggestion I have is to write a method that takes an **expression** and uses *it* to check for any nulls. But this will come at a performance cost. Anyway, it might look like:

```
T TryOrDefault<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    // Check every MemberExpression within expression one by one,
    // looking for any nulls along the way.

    // If a null is found, return default(T) or some default value.

    // Otherwise...
    Func<T> func = expression.Compile();
    return func();
}
```

Comment: I would imagine that it's probably quicker to just pass a `Func<T>`, wrap the invocation in a `try ... catch (NullReferenceException)` block and take it from there. Admittedly I haven't benchmarked this, and it feels dirty, but I suspect it would be faster, in general, than parsing, compiling and then invoking an `Expression<Func<T>>` every time.

Comment: @LukeH: You're probably right. What I *have* seen done which might make some sense is taking an `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>` and *from that* compiling a `Func<T, bool>` which will perform a one-by-one null check for every member. This `Func<T, bool>` can then be reused wherever you want to avoid having to type `if (x != null && x.Property != null)`, etc. for a particular type.

Comment: You stroke my geek, sir. An expression tree visitor that introduces null checks. And then Func.Compiles it. I will actually consider this. Time to get a ROI on the time spent reading Jon Skeets "C# in depth".

Comment: After a second glance, suddenly I understand the first line. MyObject?.Method1(SomePar):false;

Answer (score 2):

Using the [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/) operator from Ruby as inspiration, you could create an extension method that acts as a null guard.

```
public static U AndAnd<T, U>(this T obj, Func<T, U> func)
{
    return obj == null ? default(U) : func(obj);
}
```

Your original code could then be rewritten as follows:

```
SomeSource.Where(srcItem => (srcItem.AndAnd(val => val.DataMembers["SomeText"]).AndAnd(val => val.Connection).AndAnd(val => val.ConnectedTo) as Type1).AndAnd(val => val.Handler).AndAnd(val => val.ForceInvocation));
```

Do be careful when returning non-boolean value types using this method - make sure you are [familiar with the values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) returned by `default(U)`.

Comment: Job security FTW!! That was a delightful puzzle, but the end result, ie the way I eventually would be able to express it, wasn't exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @Tormod Your comment made me LOL. +1

Comment: That's a nice solution. Really simple and easier than what I was proposing with DynamicProxy. No need for external dependencies or the overhead of proxies. It seemed like a drawback initially that it works only with one part of the path, but so is AndAnd or Try in Ruby. After using this approach it's actually better that you only AndAnd the parts that might actually be null instead of recursively proxying everything as with my library.

Answer (score 0):

> create a separate func for it

This is the way to go.  Do not be allergic to proper techniques.  Methods you create are no more expensive (at runtime, and conceptually) than anonymous methods.

Comment: Perhaps that came out wrong. The performance differenece is wether or not to handle the null reference exception (for performance/scalability reasons) or a bunch of null checks (regardless of their wrapping). But my gut difference is that it is wrong to be unduly explicit about the many ways in which a specific condition can be false when there is only one way it can be true.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wrote a project that mimics AndAnd that relies on DynamicProxy. It works fine, although I've not used it in prod. The only drawback is that it requires all of the members to be virtual or the returned types to be an interface so DynamicProxy can do its magic.

Check it here
https://bitbucket.org/mamadero/andand/overview