# Is there a static method for checking if any method in an invocation chain returns null?

Tags: java

I have a situation in which I am returned an object which may or may not be completely initialized, in a way similar to this question:

[Null coalescing within an invocation chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958133/null-coalescing-within-an-invocation-chain)

I realize that the linked question is a C# question, but it remains relevant to Java.

It seems like it should be possible to make something like this in Java, using reflection. A common pattern is to use getters and setters, so we would want to be able to repeatedly invoke getters, while looking for a null. The method would look something like this:

```
public static Object coalesce(Object root, String... methods);
```

So, you would end up doing something like this:

```
Dog dog = new dog();
dog.setFur(new Fur());
dog.getFur().setColor(new Color());
// And so on
Object.coalesce(dog, "getFur", "getColor", "getRGBValues", "getRed");
```

The result would either be the result of dog.getFur().getColor().getRGBValues().getRed(), or it would be null if dog or the result of any of those methods is null.

Does something like this exist? I've done extensive regex-based searching on the Java API, but I have found nothing. It would make sense for something like this to exist, though.

Edit:

Short version, it looks like something like this doesn't exist out-of-the-box. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Try an expression language like OGNL.

Comment: Java is not perfect (right now), but working with strings and reflection you will lost a lot of the compiler safe benefits.

Comment: That way you will lose all the benefits of a typed language. In JDK8 you will be able to use method expressions to implement such a method, probably someone has already done so :) `coalesce(dog, Dog::getFur, Fur::getColor, Color::getRGBValues, RGBValues::getRed)`

Comment: Honestly, I want this largely because I want something succinct and easy-to-read. Having a ridiculous number of ___ == null tests will end up with one or more tests being neglected in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Expression Language (javax.el) can be used stand-alone. However doing it yourself is possible too. Also there are some Bean utils maybe doing the same.

```
public static Object coalesce(Object root, String... methods) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for (String methodName : methods) {
        Class<?> klazz = root.getClass();
        try {
            Method method = klazz.getMethod(methodName);
            Object result = method.invoke(root);
            root = result;
            if (root == null) {
                break;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Definitely make a nice informative error message.
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Just to follow up - I looked through Bean utils and didn't see anything like this. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: @user3062330 [JXPath](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2007/jw-03-jxpath.html) is what I meant; an XPath for plain old java objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd probably have to loop through each of the supplied  methods and check the return type:

```
    Method method = <your object>.class.getMethod(<method name>));
    if (method.getReturnType() == Void.TYPE) {
         // has a void return type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work, but it is exceptionally ugly, and not type safe.

What you really want is a combinator like (not really Java)

```
  static <A,B,C> C comb(Function<A,B> f, Function<B,C> g) {
      return new Function<A,C>() {
           public C apply(A item) {
               B b = f.apply(item); 
              if (B == null) return null;
              return g.apply(b);
  };}
```

and then:

```
comb(Dog::getFur, 
   comb(Fur::getColor, 
   comb(Color::getRGBValues, RGB::getRed))).apply(dog);
```

Maybe you can make such a thing with Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment this has to be an answer.

I assume you want to do this for lots of different objects, otherwise you could just use a simple test.  For this sort of *crosscutting concern* you might want to check out AspectJ.  It does a really good job matching method signatures and wrapping / extending / short circuiting their behavior.  It is particularly useful if you don't have the original source code.

Answer (score 0):

Then, why not simply

```
Result result = null;
try {
    result = obj.getThis().getThat().getAnother(). ... .getLast();
 } catch (NullPointerException x) {}
```

Comment: That was the other thing I was thinking. But basically, checking for nulls is already just in an if/else block, and I was wondering if there was a way to do it in one line that wouldn't involve rewriting that section.